# try catch for a specific character on input in textbox

Tags: c#, error-handling

My code currently looks like this:

```
private void logBtn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String email = textBox1.Text;
    String password = textBox2.Text;

    if (email.Contains("@"))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Valid email!");
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid email address");
    }
}
```

I'd like to be able to use a try-catch to display an error message if the email string contains the `"@"` character - is this possible? I'm aware that it might not be a good way of doing this, and that checking for an @ character isn't really a good way to verify that an input is a legit email, but I'd still like to be able to perform this with a try catch if possible.

Comment: Don't use try catch for checking if an character is in the string. The if else is much better, try catch is used for exception handling. What is wrong with the current situation?

Comment: Try-catch needs to be used in case if there is a possibility of getting exception. In your code, I don't see any such case. Moreover, things which are done by if-else can't be replaced by try-catch. Both are for different purpose.

Comment: OP, as stated a few times over (even by yourself), this is not a great approach. User input failing validation is not, typically, seen as 'exceptional', so exceptions are a bit heavy-handed here. That said, you need to throw one yourself  given a failure to satisfy your `if` condition.

Comment: @Steve - asinine's a bit excessive. It's not the typical approach, but if this was supposed to have been validated prior to this code block, I guess it would be rather exceptional that it still fails the check.

Comment: I think the elephant in the room is: Why do you want to use try-catch? What are you trying to achieve? Do you want to learn exception handling or do you care about a particular implementation? Where did you get the impression that you should use try-catch, etc.

Comment: @JᴀʏMᴇᴇ peraphs it is eccessive and (as not being a native english speaker)  I am not sure what is the acceptable word to use here, but this is the reaction I would feel if I see code that throws an exception when a simple if could solve the problem.

Comment: If you are trying to demostrate the try/catch usage then try to open a non-existant file and show the proper handling of this more plausible scenario. Not sure if using exceptions in a place where they don't need to be is a good thing to show in a demo

Answer (score 1):

> I'd still like to be able to perform this with a try catch if possible

You can, but you shouldn't. `try...catch` blocks are for uncontrolled exceptions, like a disk that is full so a file can't be written or similar situations. You don't want to use this because it is deteriorating for your performance.

If you can code this out without `try...catch`, you should. When I look at your code, I think it almost does all it can do to make the check right. I would just add a null check.

Comment: Why are you telling the OP that that's not what he wants to do? It's not best practice, which he himself has outlined, but he wants to take this approach. You haven't answered his question, you've just told him the premise on which he's asking it is wrong.

Comment: I think OPs concern was more about "that checking for an @ character isn't really a good way to verify that an input is a legit email" @JᴀʏMᴇᴇ

Comment: Fair point, but you haven't addressed the requirements. It feels more like a comment, maybe pointing OP in the direction of the XY problem explanation.

Comment: Furthermore, I'm not sure I agree with `I think it almost does all it can do to make the check right` - checking for null and the presence of the '@' character isn't adequate validation for an email address.

Comment: Because OP clearly has a misunderstanding on what a try catch does and doesn't understand proper exception handling.

Comment: Feels like a comment then, I'm afraid.

Comment: @JᴀʏMᴇᴇ Which was the think OP said it was not the best thing to do, but *ignore*.

Answer (score 1):

If you must use a `try catch` you could do something like:

```
void ValidateEmail(string email) {
    if (!email.Contains("@"))
        throw new FormatException();
}
```

And surround the call to that code within a `try catch`.

However, I cannot really find a good reason why you'd want to do this.

Comment: Agreed, no real good reason (from what we know). I'd add a message to that exception for clarity.

Comment: Thanks for this - I appreciate the responses reaffirming that a try-catch is not the way to go here. I know that it's not an appropriate solution, but I am working on a small project and would like to demonstrate a working try-catch. It's simple enough, with few options for user input, that this is really the only area I can see it applying.

Comment: Why not use a try catch on a stream read, or perhaps on an external API call? You know, where its commonly used instead? To demonstrate functionality in way it isn't intended to be used, will confuse more than it will illuminate. Just my opinion.